# Is it true that $hH$ is subset of $H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $G$ be a Group and let $H <G$ and if we choose a fixed element $h \in H$ then is it always TRUE that $hH \subset H$ .If So how can we prove it.

I came to know after seeing this property being true for the following example:

$1.$ If $G=Z_6=\left\{0,1,2,3,4,5\right\}$ and $H=\left\{0,3\right\}<G$

we have $0+H \subset H$ and $3+H \subset H$

EDIT:
According to the claim of Geoffrey:

we have $hH=H$

but while proving theorem $19.2$ in this link http://people.virginia.edu/~mve2x/3354_Spring2015/lecture19.pdf

the author has taken the following steps:

If $g^{-1}k=h$

Then $k=gh$

$\implies$

$kH=(gh)H$
$\implies$
$kH=g(hH)$

Then $kH \subseteq gH$

But since $hH=H$ why can't we write directly conclude $kH=gH$

Comment: In fact, $hH=H$ for any $h \in H$.

Comment: Note that with $\mathbb{Z}_6$, the operation is addition, so you should not write $0H$ and $3H$, but rather you should be writing $0+H$ and $3+H$.

Comment: For your new edit, here $g$ and $k$ are not in $H$ but rather arbitrary elements of the group that satisfy $g^{-1}k \in H$.

Comment: No, it is assumed that  $h \in H$ in the Hypothesis

Comment: Sorry I meant to write that $g$ and $k$ are (not necessarily) in $H$. In fact the author uses the fact that $h \in H$ so that they can write $g(hH) = gH$.

Comment: If $kH=gH$, then it is also true that $kH\subseteq gH$. Yes, the cosets are equal (because two cosets are either identical or disjoint). It is also true that one contains the other. But the authors have not yet proven that $hH=H$, and they only need the inclusion, so they do not prove the stronger statement because they don’t need it.

Comment: Regarding "$kH = gH$":  I see nothing requiring that each of $k$ and $g$ are elements of $H$ and I *do* see that $h \in H$.  This matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authors have not proven that $hH=H$ for all $h\in H$ when they are proving Theorem 19.2; as such, they cannot invoke that result. Instead, they simply note that for every $x\in H$, since $h,x$ are both in $H$, then $hx\in H$, hence $hH\subseteq H$. This suffices for their purposes, which is to show that if $g^{-1}k\in H$ then $gH=kH$, since they can use that inclusion to show that $kH\subseteq gH$ (and then symmetrically, using the fact that $k^{-1}g=(g^{-1}k)^{-1}$ is also in $H$) that $gH\subseteq kH$.

In fact, this result can be used to prove that $hH=H$ for all $h\in H$, since we will have $he^{-1}=h\in H$, hence $hH=eH=H$.

It can also be proven directly; as noted above, we have that $hH\subseteq H$. To prove the converse inclusion, let $x\in H$. Then $h^{-1}x\in H$ as well, since both $h^{-1}$ and $x$ are in $H$; then $x=h(h^{-1}x)\in hH$. Thus, $H\subseteq hH$, proving the equality.

Answer (score 5):

Hint:  $H$ is a subgroup, so $H$ is closed under the operation.

Answer (score 0):

If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $h \in H$, then $hH = H$. This is because $hH \subseteq H$ since $H$ being a group is closed under the group operation, and given an arbitrary arbitrary $k \in H$, since $H$ is a group and $h \in H$ we know $h^{-1} \in H$ and so if $k \in H$ then $h^{-1}k \in H$ so $k = hh^{-1}k \in hH$, and since $k \in H$ was arbitrary $hH \subseteq H$. Hence $hH = H$.

That being said I have seen people use "$<$" to denote subset instead of subgroup, so if $H$ is a subset but not necessarily a subgroup then $hH$ might not be a subset of $H$. For example if $\textbf{Z}_6$ and $H = \{1, 2, 3\}$ and $h = 2$ then $hH = \{3, 4, 5\}$